# Repeater headertemplate find <ul> on ItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, findcontrol

I am trying to add an attribute to a  tag with ID 'SubNav2' on ItemDataBound which is in the HeaderTemplate of a repeater.

But I keep getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which i think is because it is not finding the object with ID 'SubNav2', am i going about it the correct way?

CODE BEHIND

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then

        Dim ulSubNav2 As HtmlGenericControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("SubNav2"), HtmlGenericControl)
        ulSubNav2.Style.Add("display", "block")

    End If
```

Additonal Code
So the  i'm trying to find is in the second repeater ID=reSubNav2. Does it have to have runat=server on it?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reSubNav" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="SubNavLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>

            <asp:Repeater ID="reSubNav2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="reSubNav2_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul id="SubNav2" style="display:none;">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <li><asp:HyperLink ID="SubNavLink2" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <ul>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
    Protected Sub reSubNav2_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim rowView As System.Data.DataRowView
        rowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)

    ElseIf e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then

        Dim ulSubNav2 As HtmlGenericControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("SubNav2"), HtmlGenericControl)
        ulSubNav2.Style.Add("display", "block")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the code looks fine. Not sure why it can not find the SubNav2. Can you post some more code?

Comment: Hmm...strange, posted more code above, thanks for help.

Comment: yep just looked at it as you can not put runat="server" on the ul tag it will never be seen on server side so your can only make this work using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the UL has the runat="server" tag, and you should be able to find it.

**EDIT**

Instead of running the whole list at the server, try just running the list item at the server, like this:

```
<ul>
   <li id="listItem" runat="server">Hello!</li>
</ul>
```

If that doesn't give any errors, you should be able to access it in code behind like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl ctrl = e.Item.FindControl("listItem");
```

Comment: I've tried that but I get an error: Error creating control - reSubNav Unexpected end of file looking for </ul> tag (the </ul> tag is in the FooterTemplate). I've added more code above.

Comment: Oh! I see what you're doing. Is there a reason why you can't do this with just JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah but what i'm trying to do is change the display:none on the <ul> tag so need to find that. There are about 10 sections each with a hidden subnav and i want to show the correct subnav dependant on which section they have selected.

Comment: would e.Item.FindControl("listItem").Parent do it??

Comment: @JBoom: Can you set it up so that all of the items are nested within list items? Are you trying to create an accordion menu?

Comment: Naa it didn't. I'm not trying to create an accordion menu, theres isn't any javascript involved, i want to eventially just show one sub menu which to acheive I need to find the <ul> tag. I'm sure I can do it another way without the second repeater, just produce all the html in code behind, then I can add in display:none or block on whichever <ul> i wish.

Comment: Yea, I think you'll need to find another way, because the parser is very picky about controls running at the server, and won't let you manipulate controls the way you're lookng for.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't get it working. Seek me out if you have questions with your next attempt.

Comment: I just had a bit of an idea and it worked, rather than setting the <ul> tag to display or not display, i just coded it on the whole repeater, so if the user is in a certain section it will bind the data to the sub repeater else it won't....if that makes sense!?!